# Pandas replace NaN values with respect to the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, np.nan], 'B': [1, np.nan]})
```

df.fillna(0) replaces all the NaN values with 0. But
I want to replace the NaN values in the column 'A' with 1 and in the column 'B' with 0, simultaneously. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`fillna` method also exists for `Series` objects.

```
df["A"] = df["A"].fillna(1)
df["B"] = df["B"].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df["A"].fillna(1 , inplace=True) # for col A - NaN -> 1
df["B"].fillna(0 , inplace=True) # for col B - NaN -> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it in one line

```
(df['column_name'].fillna(0,inplace=True),df['column_name'].fillna(1,inplace=True))
print(df)
```